# RMAN log update in real time

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, rman

I am using below code in a script and running them in automated fashion

```
#!/bin/bash
rman "user"/"xxx"d@rman target=/ | tee run1.restore.log

run {
allocate channel ch1;
restore database;
switch datafile all;
recover database;
}
```

Now the problem is my log file is getting update only once complete restore/recover is done. I want to get the log file updated in real time so i can keep track the restore progress. I tried RMAN logfile feature as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `log` parameter of rman like this:

```
rman target=user/pwd@dbname log='logpath.log'
```

Or you can spool the log within RMAN prompt like this:

```
RMAN> SPOOL LOG to 'logpath.log'
```